# Using LADB: "sm partition" does not show any differnce in internal storage

Tags: adb, samsung, internal-storage, sd-card, adoptable-storage

Using LADB (Local ADB Shell App) i tried turning my SD card into expandable internal storage (or adoptable storage, which isnt availabe on my samsung).
I am unfortunatly not able to connect my phone to a computer, but it should work the same through the local shell.

The command `sm partition disk:179,32 private` or even `sm partition disk:179,32 mixed 50` should expand my current internal storage. The "mixed" option even shows half of the original cards storage as a secondary sd card in my file system, but there is no change in internal storage at all. `sm partition disk:179,32 public` is not effecitve as well.

Maybe it just doesnt show any difference, but i want to be sure that this worked, and if not - why?